# How to perform transpose to each page of nd array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I am trying to figure out how to import large array of data into 3D matrix to a specific order. I have already asked two question but i have not get reliable answer yet and get down voted too. Since then i have done some work and was able to import data to 3D matrix using `reshape` function. Instead of shooting actual problem, this is a simulation of actual problem.

```
k=1:27 % create a array of 27 data
r=reshape(k,[3,3,3]) % convert the array into 3 x 3 x 3 matrix,
```

The results of the first page and second of the matrix is, the data is placed along the columns, but i wanted to place them along rows, The `transpose` function does not work with ND arrays, I tried to use `permute` but i did not get the desired result, One solution will be perform `transpose` to each page, but that will break the 3D matrix in to many 2D matrices.

```
r(:,:,1) =

 1     4     7
 2     5     8
 3     6     9

r(:,:,2) =

10    13    16
11    14    17
12    15    18
```

## the expected outcome should be,

```
r(:,:,1) =

 1     2     3
 4     5     6
 7     8     9
```

[Link to the actual problem is,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400203/reading-a-raw-data-file-into-a-2d-or-3d-array-for-data-manipulation)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
result = permute(r, [2 1 3]);
```

This permutes the first two dimensions. For your example `r`,

```
>> k = 1:27;
>> r = reshape(k, [3,3,3]);
>> result = permute(r, [2 1 3]);
>> result
result(:,:,1) =
     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
result(:,:,2) =
    10    11    12
    13    14    15
    16    17    18
result(:,:,3) =
    19    20    21
    22    23    24
    25    26    27
```

Comment: I already tried it, but you can see it does not work, In the first page first row should be 1,2,3 not 1,4,7.

Comment: @Manoj Sorry, edited. Please see now

Comment: Thanks it worked, I think i was fooled by the intermediate result given by the matlab, when the result is checked, the answer is in correct order, Many thanks , this has saved lot of time,

Comment: Glad I could help!